# Determin if GitHub Issue Already Exists

Tags: java, git, error-reporting, jcabi

I have been writing a error reporter to automatically report exceptions from my Minecraft mod to my GitHub issue page. It works, but my code that checks if the issue already exists is not working. I am using [jcabi](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-github) for my interaction with GitHub. If you need additional information, let me know. Thanks!

Code that determines if the issue already exists:

```
private static boolean DoesIssueAlreadyExist(String Title, String Report)
{
    try
    {
        int i = 0;
        int size = GetNumberOfIssues();
        Issue.Smart Current;

        while (i != size)
        {
            Current = new Issue.Smart(repo.issues().get(i));

            if (Current.title() == Title && Current.body() == Report)
            {
                    return true;
            }

            i++;
        }

        return false;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Code that starts my process of message generation and issue creation:

```
private static Github github = new RtGithub(Secure.Token);
private static Repo repo = github.repos().get( new Coordinates.Simple("SneakyTactician/BIGB2"));

public static void Report(Exception ToReport)
{
    try 
    {       
        //The title for the issue.
        String Title = ToReport.getMessage();
        //Generates a message for the issue. 
        String Report = GetMessage(ToReport);

        if (!DoesIssueAlreadyExist(Title, Report))
        {   

        Issue TheIssue = repo.issues().create(Title, Report);
        Issue.Smart a = new Issue.Smart(TheIssue);
        a.assign("SneakyTactician");

        a.labels().add(extracted());
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Example issue title:

/ by zero

Example issue body:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at sneaky.main.Startup.preInit(Startup.java:28)
at sneaky.main.BIGB2.preInit(BIGB2.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:641)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:246)
at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:224)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:147)
at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.preinitializeMods(Loader.java:628)
at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:268)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:440)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:352)
at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
```

6number of mods were found running:

Minecraft 1.11.2

Minecraft Coder Pack 9.19

Forge Mod Loader 8.0.99.99

Minecraft Forge 13.20.0.2228

mercurius_updater 1.0

Because I Got Bored 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of puzzling and frustration, I figured it out! The below method checks to see if the issue already exists on your GitHub issues page.

```
/**
 * Determines if the exception has already been posted to the issue page.
 * Returns false if an error occurs.
 * @param e
 * @return
 */
private static boolean DoesIssueAlreadyExist(String Title, String Report)
{  
  try
    {
        EnumMap<Qualifier, String> qualifiers = new EnumMap<Qualifier, String>(Issues.Qualifier.class);

        Iterable<Issue> Issues = repo.issues().search(Sort.CREATED, Order.DESC, qualifiers);

        Issue.Smart current;

        long size = Iterables.size(Issues);

        int i = 0;


        while (i != size)
        {
            current = new Issue.Smart(Issues.iterator().next());

            if (current.title().contains(Title) && current.body().contains(Report))
            { 
                return true;
            }

            i++;
        }

        return false;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return true;
    }
}
```